# angular router how to call child component from the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have the following route-

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: ChildComponent,
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

in the constructor of the parent I want to navigate to some id, for example 'test'.
I tried this-

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.navigate(['child']);
}
```

and this-

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.navigate(['/child']);
}
```

and this-

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.navigate(['./child']);
}
```

and this-

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.navigate(['../child']);
    }
```

my url is - http://localhost:4200/parent.

but all of this options I go to http://localhost:4200/child instead of http://localhost:4200/parent/child

Any idea why? how can I make it relative to the parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `navigate` takes in absolute paths.

You have to explicitly tell it to be relative :

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  this.router.navigate(['child'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: I have another question- in the constructor of the parent I need to know if I have id in the url or not, and if I don't have, I need to add a default one. Do you know how can I recognize in the parent that in the url I have the id? this.route.snapshot.params.id returns undefined.

Comment: Snapshots are deprecated, try `this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.router.navigate(...))`

Comment: params are empty also when I have an id in the url, something like-  http://localhost:4200/parent/child. I want to know if I have a child id in the url.

Comment: this.route.snapshot.firstChild works! it recognize the child inside the parent component.